# How can I fix my error when I start my React-Native App?

Tags: javascript, react-native, npm, npm-install

I'm creating a new React-Native app. I'm following the React-Native [quickstart](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started) When I want to start my app with "expo start" I got this error :

```
Error: spawn cmd ENOENT
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:246:19)
at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:427:16)
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/next_tick.js:76:17)
```

Thank you !

Comment: If you're using Windows, this could be due to the fact that you're missing the ``C:\Windows\System32\`` environment path, or take a look here: https://github.com/expo/expo/issues/2122

Comment: Omg Thank you !